# facebook app link creation with branch.io

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I'm wondering if Branch IO can cater for my use case.

I need to create a link that can do the following:

1. If the user is on a PC, direct them to the facebook website in their browser

   eg. https://www.facebook.com/pg/sony
2. If the user is on IOS/Android and has the facebook app installed, deeplink them to the facebook app

   eg. IOS: fb://page/sony
   eg. ANDROID: fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/sony
3. If the user is on IOS/Android and DOESN'T have the facebook app installed, send them to the facebook website via a browser

   eg. https://www.facebook.com/pg/sony

I can do everything except step 3 with javascript, and in googling for an answer some have suggested that branch IO can help. I've struggled to make this work - here is the rule I have tried (I have removed my key on purpose)

> curl -XPOST https://api.branch.io/v1/url \
>
> -d '{
>
> "branch_key": "my_key_removed_for_this_demo_purpose",
>
> "channel": "facebook",
>
> "campaign": "test",
>
> "data": {
>
> "$ios_url": "fb://page/sony",
>
> "$desktop_url": "https://www.facebook.com/pg/sony",
>
> "$android_url": "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/sony",
>
> "$fallback_url": "https://www.facebook.com/pg/sony"
>
> }
>
> }'

When I attempt to access this link in chrome from my android phone, I'm greeted with a message stating "To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app".

Is my use case possible with Branch IO? (ie integrating with facebook & directing the user to the app if it is installed, otherwise using their browser & navigating to the appropriate facebook page).

I would really appreciate some help in making this work

Many thanks

Comment: Edit: After deselecting the "I have an IOS App / I have an Android App" in the "Link Settings" of the branch IO console - the Android link now works and opens via the facebook app. The problem is, if the facebook app is disabled (I can't actually uninstall it as it's a 'system app'), the Branch.IO link now does nothing. If the Facebook app isn't installed or is disabled, I want it to use the fallback URL and open facebook in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting the uri_redirect_mode to make sure that the URI scheme is fired only when the app is present. You could read more on uri_redirect_mode [here](https://blog.branch.io/making-uri-schemes-great-again-uri_redirect_mode/). If you are still facing issues, please write to integrations@branch.io and we would be happy to help you out.

Comment: Will this work for an app that is not mine? (ie. the facebook app). Further research has lead me to believe that branch.io can only help if the SDK is present in the app - which wouldn't be the case with the facebook app

Comment: Yes. that is true, it will open any app, if the app has Branch SDK integrated in it